# C# webBroswer component override the window.print from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

I have a web application that does a bunch of things, and need to write a C# program to print a document that is generated by the system.

When a user clicks the print button on the web form (`window.print()`), it will print to a specific printer without popping up the print dialog box.

I tried `webbrowser.print()`, but it only prints the web interface without the pop up.

One of the things that I'm looking for is a way to handle a print job created by the website. I want the C# program to be able to remove the print dialog box and print directly to the printer.

Can anyone give me a hint as to how I can go about implementing this, or explain why (if) this isn't possible?

P.S. I cannot change anything in the web application. That is why I want to write a C# program to perform/manage this additional action.

Answer (score 0):

you have a webbrowser control on the c# form? do this:

myBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ButtonId").InvokeMember("click");

it automatically click the button.

if the button does not have id, then you will need to use either its class or tag to identify that button. Search "click button automatically in webbrowser control".

Comment: Yes, i am using webbrowser control with the C# form. Actually, there is existing javascript calling "windows.print()" on web form. And it will pop up the windows for printer option. What i want to do is...if i detect windows.print is running. Then i use C# webBrowser1.Print() instead. It will not have a printer pop up.

Answer (score 0):

Try injecting script inside the web page from C# code

Something similar to on some C# app button click . .

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "function printDocument() { window.print(); }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("printDocument");
```

or simply

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "window.print();");
```